# Find the volume of Region R using convenient method

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> 5. Let R be the region bound by the parabola $y=x^2$ and the line $y=-x+2$
>
> a)Calculate the  volume  of  the  solid about  $x=-2$

It appears in my guide, i think solving it using washer method, and integrating in y-terms.

I know the formula of the concentric washer method is :

$$\ 2\pi\int_a^b\Delta x(f(x))dx $$

In this cross-section, the line is greater than the parabol, and i said that the height $y \in[0,4]$ is $(y-2-\sqrt y)$

And my integration setup looks like this :

$$2\pi\int_0^4(y-2-\sqrt y)(y+2)dy$$

Any other method?

And it's supposed that the region about x and y axis may be the same value, in the before exercise , i've had integrating in x terms and rotating about y=0 and this integration is $correct$.

$$V= \int_{-2}^1(-x+2)^2-(x^2)^2dx$$

Equals to : $\cfrac {72\pi}{5}$

Comment: There is no reason at all to suppose that the solids of rotation about different axes are going to have the same volume. In fact it is quite obvious that they would not. Even when the axes are parallel, rotating around the one farther away will obviously produce a larger volume. For non parallel axes, consider the example of a circle: rotate it about a line in the same plane, and you get a torus with volume. Rotate it about a line perpendicular to the plane, and you get a planar figure with no volume at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Washer Method" for calculating the volume of a solid of rotation is:

- You integrate along the axis of rotation. I.e., along the height $h$.
- For each height on the axis, you intersect the solid with the plane perpendicular to the axis. This intersection is an annulus ("washer" shape). Its area is $\pi(R^2 - r^2)$ where $R$ is the radius of the outer circle, and $r$ is the radius of the inner circle. These two radii change with $h$, so they can be expressed as functions: $r(h), R(h)$.
- The volume is the integral of the areas from the minimum height $h_0$ to the maximum height $h_1$, so
  $$V = \pi\int_{h_0}^{h_1} R^2(h) - r^2(h)\, dh$$

By analogy, the other method should be called the "Bushing Method". But alas, everybody knows what washers and cylinders look like, while far fewer people know what an annulus or a bushing looks like. So we get a mix of calling one method by the hardware name and the other by the mathematical shape name. The "Cylinder Method" is:

- You integrate perpendicular to the axis of rotation. I.e., along the radius $r$.
- For each radius from the axis, you intersect the solid with the cylinder ("bushing" shape) of that radius about the axis. The intersection will have a constant height $\Delta h$ all the way around. So the area of the cylinder is the circumference times the height. I.e., $2\pi r \Delta h$. While the height doesn't change as you go around the rotation, it does change with the radius. So it should be expressed as a function $\Delta h(r)$.
- The volume is the integral of the areas from the minimum radius $r_0$ to the maximum radius $r_1$, so $$V = 2\pi\int_{r_0}^{r_1} r\Delta h(r)\,dr$$

Your formula appears to be a confusion of these two. The axis of rotation is the vertical line $x = -2$. Applying the washer method, you would integrate along it, which is the $y$ direction. So $y$ takes the place of $h$. But as you can see, you've got the formula for the cylinder method, not the washer method. To use the washer method, you need to spit the integral in two parts. The line intersects the parabola at the points $(-2, 4)$ and $(1,1)$. The inner radius (distance from the axis to the inner surface) is always given by $r(y) = 2-\sqrt y$. The outer radius (distance from the axis to the outer surface) is given by $R(y) = 2 + \sqrt y$ for $y \le 1$ and by $R(y) = 4 - y$ for $y > 1$. So the volume is given by

$$V = \pi\int_0^1 (2 + \sqrt y)^2 - (2 - \sqrt y)^2\, dy + \pi\int_1^4 (4-y)^2 - (2 - \sqrt y)^2\, dy$$

Not a particularly nice integral, but doable.

If we try the cylinder method instead, we need to integrate in the direction perpendicular to the axis of rotation. I.e., we integrate along $x$. But since the axis is at $x = -2$, the radius $r$ is $r = x + 2$. The height, expressed as a function of $x$ is just the difference in the $y$ values of the two curves: $(-x + 2) - x^2$. So the volume is given by $$V = 2\pi\int_{-2}^{1}(x+2)\big((-x + 2) - x^2\big)\, dx$$

Which is a much nicer integral.